# Javascript Runs out of Memory when connecting to Postgres Database With Defined Entities in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to connect to a Postgres Database running on my local computer with Typescript and TypeORM. This is part of updating an existing project to use TypeORM, so there is a bunch of existing code which has been removed from the snippets as it isn't relevant. However, I get the following errors when attempting to connect:

```
Creating connection to database...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[1372461:0x6370180]    58249 ms: Scavenge 2040.6 (2051.6) -> 2039.1 (2051.6) MB, 4.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.198, current mu = 0.186) allocation failure 
[1372461:0x6370180]    58260 ms: Scavenge 2040.9 (2051.6) -> 2039.4 (2051.8) MB, 3.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.198, current mu = 0.186) allocation failure 
[1372461:0x6370180]    58271 ms: Scavenge 2041.1 (2055.8) -> 2039.7 (2056.1) MB, 3.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.198, current mu = 0.186) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb797be v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb79b37 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd343c5  [node]
 6: 0xd34f4f  [node]
 7: 0xd42fdb v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd46b9c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 9: 0xd1527b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
10: 0x105b21f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
11: 0x14011f9  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

However, that only happens when I have defined entities for TypeScript to use in the ormconfig.json file. When I replace the `"entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"]` line with `"entities": ["src/entity/fakeFileName.ts"]` I can successfully connect to my database. The confusion comes from the fact that I created a new, minimal case test project using `typeorm init --name MyProject --database postgres` from the TypeORM docs and ported my entities over to that project, and the connection worked fine.

My ormconfig file:

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "postgres",
   "password": "postgres",
   "database": "test_database",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": false,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

The two entities I defined:
Dispatched:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  BaseEntity
} from 'typeorm';

import {
  Requests
} from './requests';

@Entity()
export class Dispatched extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Requests, (request) => requests.dispatched)
  requests: Requests
}
```

and Requests:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryColumn,
  Column,
  OneToMany,
  BaseEntity
} from 'typeorm';

import {
  Dispatched
} from './Dispatched';

type repeatOptions = 'single' | 'perpetual';

@Entity()
export class Requests extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    requestID: string;

    @Column()
    templateUUID: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    source: string | undefined;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    description: string | undefined;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    name: string | undefined;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    referenceId: string | undefined;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    metadata: string | undefined;

    @Column({
      type: 'enum',
      enum: ['single', 'perpetual'],
      default: 'single'
    })
    dispatchRepeat: repeatOptions | undefined;

    @Column()
    isFulfilled: boolean;

    @OneToMany(() => Dispatched, (dispatched) => dispatched.request)
    dispatched: Dispatched[];
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,


    "strictNullChecks": true,

    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test Project",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.4",
    "npm": "6.14.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean-dist": "rm -rf dist",
    "compile": "npm run clean-dist && tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node -r esm dist/index.js",
  },
  "author": "rloveless",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@koa/cors": "^3.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "command-line-args": "^5.1.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "koa": "^2.13.0",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-mount": "^4.0.0",
    "koa-proxy": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "koa-router": "^10.0.0",
    "koa-ts-controllers": "^2.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "pg": "8.6.0",
    "react-act": "^1.0.1",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-act": "^1.8.0",
    "redux-dynamic-middlewares": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-saga-requests": "^0.27.0",
    "redux-saga-thunk": "^0.7.3",
    "redux-subscribe-action": "2.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "superagent": "^6.1.0",
    "typeorm": "0.2.32",
    "urljoin": "^0.1.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.0",
    "winston-syslog": "2.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@json-rpc-tools/types": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/command-line-args": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
    "@types/koa": "^2.11.6",
    "@types/koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/koa-mount": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/koa-proxy": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/koa-router": "^7.4.1",
    "@types/koa__cors": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.167",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "@types/superagent": "^4.1.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.12.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-minify": "^0.5.1",
    "eslint": "^7.15.0",
    "eslint-config-cpr": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^2.1.2",
    "fake-indexeddb": "^3.1.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": false,
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src/"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./__test__/helpers/node-shim.js"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!jsts).+\\.js$"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/(.*)/__tests__/helpers/"
    ]
  }
}
```

And the index file where I attempt to connect to the database:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

import {
  createConnection,
} from 'typeorm';

console.log('Creating connection to database...');
createConnection().then(async () => {
   // Code to start app goes here, but it is never reached
   console.log('Connection to database established, starting app...');
}).catch((error) => console.log('TypeORM connection error: ', error));
```

So, why is it that removing the entities from the ormconfig.json could solve the problem in this project, but when I use those same entities in another minimal use case there is no problem?